# How to change place of text in echo?

Tags: php

I'm setting up a script for a friend, I want the `landing_{random}` to be added after the domain names but I whatever I do it shows behind the URL. How can I fix this issue?

I have tried moving the variables around and reversing places with the variables.

```
<?php
    $lines = file('domains.txt');
    foreach($lines as $line) {
        $randomString = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdef"), 0, 1) . 
        substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdef"), 0, 6);
        $landing = "/landing_$randomString";
        /*echo "$line.'/landing_'.$randomString";*/
        echo "$line{$landing}";
    }
?>
```

I want when I input URL in http://example.com in domains.txt for it to output http://example.com/landing_d2ae5b3

Comment: For your example, your code works fine. Can you give an example of it not working?

Comment: I want the path and domain be on the same line so i can use API to shorten the link for traffic analysis. but when I run the code i posted it return with a line break. domain line break then path.

Comment: I fixed it the issue was line break i added preg_replace and removed now all work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work like that    Try instead:

```
$landing = '/landing_".$randomString."';
```

Should work fine now

Update answer

Try this

```
$landing = "/landing_".$randomString."";
```

By the way I think you may need to define array before use it like

```
$lines = explode("" ,$lines);

//then
$landing = "/landing_".$randomString."";
```

Also you may use this :

```
echo "$line".$landing."";
```

Comment: I changed my path to $path = '/invoice_'.$randomString.''; and added {$path} in my domain variable still giving same output. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I made many scripts for that purpose it's always needed in APIs especially when defining images names  so the extension still like .jpg but name change with data. If the answer update doesn't work let me know I will examine the script and adapt it just provide .txt file content example in your comment.